# Tower Defense Mob Health

Tags: java

I am working on a Tower Defense game and am running into a huge problem when it comes to fixating the health of stronger mobs as levels increase. I currently have the health set to the mobSize (by that I mean, the health bar is proportioned to the size of the mob). This obviously wont work for higher levels, since the mobs stay the same size and get stronger but my draw() method does this :

```
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    if(inGame) {
        if(Screen.level == 1){
        g.drawImage(Screen.tileset_mob[1], x, y, width, height, null);
        //Health Bar
        g.setColor(new Color(180, 180, 50));
        g.fillRect(x, y -(healthSpace + healthHeight) , width, healthHeight);      

        g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        g.fillRect(x, y -(healthSpace + healthHeight) , mobshealth , healthHeight);

        g.setColor(new Color (0, 0, 0));
        g.drawRect(x, y -(healthSpace + healthHeight), mobshealth - 1, healthHeight -1);
        }
```

This clearly just removes from the width of the health bar, which is set as the health of the mob. My problem is, I want to make a stronger mob that will take away less from the health bar as the levels increase. Any Suggestions? Thank you so much!

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to have the health bar stay the same size for mobs that have different max health?

Comment: yes thats exactly what I want!

Answer (score 3):

A property of a logical entity should have nothing to do with its visual representation, but rather quite the opposite.

In other words you should not concern yourself with anything to do with drawing or GUI, but rather make your Mob class (the logical class, not its visual representation) allow for some type of strength multiplier factor that can be applied to its size attribute and then returned in its `getStrength()` method. The visual representation will simply reflect the value returned by this method.

i.e.,:

```
// strengthScaleFactor is a double which increases at higher levels
public int getStrength() {
   return (int) (getMobSize() * strengthScaleFactor);
}
```

The visual representation of the mob's strength, the "health bar", could calculate and use the normalized strength level, that is the result from the method above divided by some other method that returns the maximum Strength (`getMaxStrength()` perhaps?).

Think [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) all the way here.

Answer (score 0):

Think MVC

```
//Model fields
//HP, MAXHP

//Controller method
float getHPPercent()
{
return HP/HPMax(float);
}

//View

int HPBoxWidthInPixels
Draw()
{
float percent = controller.getHPPercent();
Rect HPBox.x = Math.RoundToInt(HPBoxWidthInPixels *percent);
}
```